# Fruit is cut into smaller pieces like a chip and then boiled dried in sugar. Are they called "papaya/banana…chips" or "papaya/banana…jams"?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-request, phrase-request, phrase-choice

We cut fruit such as papayas, bananas, mangoes, etc into thin pieces which has the same size as a potato chip and we **boil them dried** in sugar (**Note**: I am not sure if "*boil something dried*" is a correct expression, it means boils them until they are dried).

These fruit chips/jams can be stored for months.

Are they called "**papaya/banana…chips**" or "**papaya/banana…jams**"?

Chips often refer to potato chips and are boiled in oil. Chips are normally salty not sweet.

Jam is often a **thick liquid** not **thin liquid** (**Note**: I'm not sure "**thick/thin liquid**" is a correct way of saying) like this.

[image]

**The below is the squash chips or jams (they are very popular in Asia)?**

[image]

These are yum banana chips (the whole small bananas were boiled, they are not **cut small**) (**Note**: I'm not sure "**cut it small**" is correct)

[image]

Bigger bananas can be **cut sideways** (**Note**: I'm not sure "**cut it sideways**" is correct) before boiled.

[image]

Some Indian people say they are "**candied banana/papaya...**" or "**candied fruit**"

> [candied](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/candied?q=Candied) adjective  /ˈkændid/  /ˈkændid/ [only before noun]
>
> ​(of fruit or other food) preserved by boiling in sugar; cooked in
> sugar
>
> candied fruit
>
> candied peel (= of oranges)

---

I am not sure if we can say "**banana/papaya... candy**" or "**fruit candy**".

Comment: @JamesK, you can see yum banana chips in my updated question

Comment: My banana chips are like those in the link supplied by Accumulation, below - cut across rather than lengthways.

Comment: "thick" and "thin" liquid is correct. Thick liquids are also called viscous, but that's more of a scientific term. "cut sideways" is also an acceptable way to say that, though I'd personally say "cut longways" to emphasize that it's cut along the long dimension of the banana. "fruit candy", to me, would imply fruit-flavored candy more than candied fruits, but again, it's not wrong to say for this. And finally, "cut small" is acceptable but sounds a little bit strange to my ears as a native speaker. I'm not sure why, though; it does sound like something you'd read in a cookbook.

Comment: "Note: I'm not sure "cut it sideways" is correct)" The term for cutting bananas like that would be "cut lengthwise", I believe.

Comment: Re "boil something dried," it will be understood, but a native speaker would  say "boil *dry*" instead.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

*Jam* is a way of preserving fruit by boiling it in sugar syrup until the mixture sets. It is usually eaten spread on bread. This is quite different
from candied fruit.

Dry candied fruit pieces are indeed sometimes called chips. I have some 'crispy banana chips' in my kitchen cupboard at this moment. (Even though, in Britain, we call the salted ones crisps, not chips!)

Comment: We Americans have both *jam* and *jelly*; they aren’t quite the same thing, I believe, but I certainly couldn’t tell you what the distinction between them is (I don’t really like either).

Comment: Jam uses chunks of fruit or fruit puree. Jelly only uses fruit juice. (Both use sugar and pectin.)

Comment: The Jam/Jelly distiction is the same in British.  Jellies are made by straining the juice to remove seeds and pulp.  Jellies are less common in the UK, and "grape jelly" is unknown (as the right kind of grapes don't grow/aren't grown in Europe)  The distiction is that in BritEng, jelly is also used for a gelatine dish that Americans call Jello.

Comment: @KRyan That's interesting. I had always understood that Americans called jam _jelly_ - as mentioned [here](https://separatedbyacommonlanguage.blogspot.com/2009/06/over-counter-observations.html)

Comment: @KateBunting that understanding is common, but is largely just due to the fact that America prefers jellies, and we prefer jams, to the extent that outside of foodies, many brits are unaware of the existence of British jellies (and many Americans of American jams). Without that knowledge, jellies and jams are close enough that it is often more practical to simply think of jelly as American jam and jam as British jelly

Comment: also as a Brit I'm not sure I've ever heard candied fruit referred to as chips, at least not without also having the word "candied" included. If I saw a packet of "crispy banana chips" I would probably be surprised to find out they were candied rather than simply sliced & dried

Comment: @Tristan My banana chips (from a well-known health food chain) are 'sweetened and fried', so not exactly candied. The link I provided is to the blog of an American resident in the UK. I've been aware of redcurrant and crabapple jelly all my life, but didn't mention them so as not to complicate the issue.

Comment: @JamesK I thought that UK "jellies" were closer to what Americans call "gummies" (or "gum drops", but available in other shapes).  At least the "jelly babies" on Doctor Who seem more like gummies than Jello, which would be quite messy to keep around in a little bag in your pocket.  (Jello of course is just one brand name for gelatin.)

Comment: @DarrelHoffman We have fruit gums (very firm gelatin) and fruit  jellies/jelly babies (slightly less, but still firm enough to hold their shape, and covered in granulated sugar to they don't stick together). But jelly (uncountable) is, as James says, a preserve in which the fruit pulp has been  strained out before setting, eaten as a spread or as a relish with cooked meat. We also call the gelatin dessert jelly.

Comment: @KateBunting It gets worse. We have (at least) jam, jelly, marmalade, preserves, chutney, fruit butter, confit, and curd. https://cookerynation.com/2016/06/25/jam-jelly-marmalade-preserves/ Jelly is the most widely available, but some of the others are common for certain fruits (strawberry jam, orange marmalade, lemon curd, apple butter (not to be confused with applesauce!)) and some are more common regionally (preserves are more common in rural areas where people do more home canning).

Comment: @KateBunting The confusing thing in [that blog entry](https://separatedbyacommonlanguage.blogspot.com/2009/06/over-counter-observations.html), I think, is the reference to "peanut butter and [...] jelly". Indeed, today, in my kitchen in the U.S., I made myself a peanut-butter-and-jelly sandwich that contained no jelly; instead, I used raspberry preserves. For my peanut-butter-and-jelly sandwiches last week I used raspberry jam; again, no jelly at all. Technically, perhaps I should call these peanut-butter-and-jam sandwiches, but I never do.

Comment: @KateBunting Also along the lines of the blog entry: https://fb.watch/3ksj-oTVIV/ from 1:43 onward.

Answer (score 30):

In American usage (at least), a "fruit chip", a "fruit jam", a "candied fruit", and "fruit candy" would be four different things.  Let's take the papaya as an example.

- A "papaya chip" would be something that is crunchy or crispy in texture, made by drying thin slices of papaya fruit in a low oven, or (more likely) frying them in oil.  They would not contain any additional sugar beyond the natural sugars present in the fruit.  (I don't know if it's possible to prepare papayas in this way, but if someone asked me if I wanted "papaya chips", I would expect something like this.)
- "Papaya jam" would be made by cooking pieces of papaya with sugar (and not much additional water) until the individual pieces fell apart and the whole thing turned into a very thick liquid that could be spread on other foods.  The top picture in the OP is a jam.  (As with the "chips", I don't know whether papayas can be actually prepared in this way;  but it's what I'd expect if someone offered me "papaya jam".)
- "Candied papaya" would be papaya prepared in the method you've described:  take larger pieces of the fruit and cook them slowly in a sugar syrup until they're infused with sugar and much of the original moisture has gone into the syrup.  The pieces of fruit remain whole, not falling apart.  The pieces are often then coated with another layer of sugar crystals.  The resulting food would be quite sweet, and chewy in texture.  The bottom picture in the OP appears to be a candied fruit.
- "Papaya candy" would be a confectionary made mostly of sugar that is flavored with either natural or artificial papaya flavoring, but does not contain much (if any) real papaya fruit.  Again, this would be quite sweet.

Comment: You certainly can make papaya jam, https://www.google.com/search?q=papaya+jam  Banana jam of a sort is also possible, but the question of whether it was jam or jelly was a plot point in *The God of Small Things*.

Comment: I agree with all your definitions but I would add "dried fruit" which (in my region anyway) is solid pieces of fruit that you eat with your fingers.  It is often quite sweet but this is mostly due to the natural sweetness of the fruit so I wouldn't consider them to be the same as "candied".  Papaya is a common fruit you can buy like this as well as mango, pineapple, kiwi etc.  The difference between "dried papaya" and "papaya chip" is that the latter is crunchy and the former is chewy.

Answer (score 4):

At least in AmE, "chip" primarily refers to particularly thin objects and/or objects with one dimension significantly smaller than the other two. So, for instance, [banana chips](https://nuts.com/driedfruit/banana-chips/sweetened/1lb.html), [coconut chips](https://nuts.com/driedfruit/coconut/unsweeted-chips/1lb.html), [fruit chips](https://www.bhg.com/recipe/crispy-fruit-chips/), [wood chips](https://www.lesprom.com/en/trade/Wood_chips_from_sawmilling_334/Wood_chips_from_sawmilling_5185/). There's also [baking chips](https://www.webstaurantstore.com/regal-foods-5-lb-butterscotch-4m-baking-chips/999BSCTCHCHP.html), especially chocolate chips, which do not follow the pattern of having one dimension smaller than the others, but are small.

The noun probably derives from the verb "chip", which means to break pieces off an object through hitting that object. Thus, the term refers to objects that are, or resemble, pieces so separated. "Chip" in AmE would be a stretch when applied to these objects, although their resemblance to French(ed)[1] fried potatoes may allow them to be called "chips" in BrE.

"Candied fruit" would be acceptable; that is a general term that does not refer to shape. If you want a term that refers to shape, there's "sticks". "Fruit candy" refers to candy made out of fruit or made to appear to be made out of, or resemble, fruit; if the fruit remains intact but altered by the addition of sugar, then "candied fruit" is more appropriate.

[1]The original term was "Frenched fried potatoes", with "French" being a verb that referred to slicing food into sticks, but now generally they are just referred to as "French fries".

Comment: You have a reference for *french* being a verb? I've never ever heard that meaning before, and it's not listed in a couple of dictionaries currently listed by google. The *only* reference I found was in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/French_fries#:~:text=A%20lower%2Dfat%20method%20for,which%20also%20reduces%20acrylamide%20formation.) which certainly isn't definitive. It sounds possibly plausible though. Normally it is taken to be that french fries ("chips") originated in France, even though the Belgians actually invented french fries, a fact that they never fail to remind people of.

Comment: @Greenonline I was able to Google it reasonably easily.  It didn't come up in the Google dictionary, but it did come up in the dictionaries listed on the result page.  "to cut (green beans) in thin lengthwise strips before cooking" https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/French

Comment: I stand corrected...! Interesting, it must be a cooking term. Strangely, the Wiki entry seems to imply French means "Wedged". You should probably put that reference in your answer, so we can delete these comments.

Answer (score 1):

[Succade (Wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Succade):

> Succade is the candied peel of any of the citrus species, especially from the citron or Citrus medica which is distinct with its extra-thick peel; in addition, the taste of the inner rind of the citron is less bitter than those of the other citrus. However, the term is also occasionally applied to the peel, root, or even entire fruit or vegetable like parsley, fennel and cucurbita which have a bitter taste and **are boiled with sugar** to get a special "sweet and sour" outcome.

Comment: The second picture in the OP seems to be this.

Comment: The problem with using this term is that not many people will know what you mean, I’m afraid.

Comment: @Fivesideddice it's not "chips" anyway, because chips means thin slices, and i don't consider calling this "jam".